# How to get information about controller method inside exception handler?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have existing REST API (using Spring MVC) that whenever exception happens return default response object with `setInvalid(true)`. Currently, there are lots of try-catches.

I want to rewrite this using @ExceptionHandler, but in this case I cannot guess which type I should return (there different response classes inherited from single class). I see that there is HandlerMethod class that would allow me to do what I want but I can't find a way to access it inside exception handler.

Is there any way to implement such general behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass some data from controller to `@ExceptionHandler` then you should throw the exception by using its constructer with message parameter. 
E.g

```
catch(Exception e){
  if (ex instanceof NullPointerException) {
    throw new ABCException("Input is incorrect, Please provide proper  input.");
  }
}
```

and in the exception-handler area,

```
@ExceptionHandler(ABCException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
String handleExceptions(ABCException re) {

    log(re.toString());
    return re.getMessage();
}
```

Otherwise, if your idea is to create your own message based on the origin, then you can get the origin from the Referer, e.g.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ABCException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
@ResponseBody
String handleExceptions(ABCException re, HttpServletRequest request) {

    log(request.getHeader("Referer"););
    return something;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted to avoid all that try-catches blocks. Already implemented that feature using Spring AOP using @Around pointcut

Comment: you can collect the referer from the request then and do the processing based on that